# Analysing the RC4 key generator

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I'm just a starting php programmer, therefore Java is completly magic for me. I have a problem I need to solve. How can I calculate the RC4 key as it is in getRC4Key function using for example PHP functions? I know already that it is something like:

```
MD5(MD5(PASSWORD).BIGINTEGER_ENCODING)
```

however I don't uderstand the ByteArraysUtils.

I would appreciate any help. Here I'm attaching all methods I think are used for the purpose.

This is example of password declaration:

```
localProperties.put("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", "a33aed8f3134926783dc39f9a7f94783");
```

And this is an example of BigInteger:

```
1333353820499958118
```

This is how big integer is declared:

```
    public class ServerModel
{
  private BigInteger syncFsUid = null;
  private BigInteger syncRunId = null;
  private BigInteger syncStreamSeq = null;
  private BigInteger recordsDirectorySize = null;
  public static final BigInteger UNSIGNED_LONG_MIN = BigInteger.ZERO;
  public static final BigInteger UNSIGNED_LONG_MAX = new BigInteger("18446744073709551615");
```

This is getRC4Key function:

```
private byte[] getRC4Key(BigInteger paramBigInteger)
{
    try
{
  MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
  localMessageDigest.reset();
  localMessageDigest.update(ServerModel.getInstance().getConnection().getPassword().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
  byte[] arrayOfByte = localMessageDigest.digest();
  localMessageDigest.reset();
  localMessageDigest.update(arrayOfByte);
  localMessageDigest.update(ByteArraysUtils.BigInteger2ByteArray(paramBigInteger));
  return localMessageDigest.digest();
    }
}
```

Utils:

```
      public final class ByteArraysUtils
{
  public static final byte[] BigInteger2ByteArray(BigInteger paramBigInteger)
  {
    return BigInteger2ByteArray(paramBigInteger, ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
  }

  public static final byte[] BigInteger2ByteArray(BigInteger paramBigInteger, ByteOrder paramByteOrder)
  {
    return Long2ByteArray(paramBigInteger.longValue(), paramByteOrder);
  }

  public static final byte[] Long2ByteArray(long paramLong)
  {
    return Long2ByteArray(paramLong, ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
  }

  public static final byte[] Long2ByteArray(long paramLong, ByteOrder paramByteOrder)
  {
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer localByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arrayOfByte);
    localByteBuffer.order(paramByteOrder);
    localByteBuffer.putLong(paramLong);
    return arrayOfByte;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Could you link to the "PHP example functions" that define `getRC4Key`? Otherwise it will be hard to answer this question.

Comment: @owlstead hey, what is wrong with my question again.. I really tried hard to be more specific this time. I don't need Java to PHP conversion. I just have a excerpt of Java code which I don't understand. I think you are too critical. People can ask for "1+1" answer and get it, but when I don't understand all those "ByteArraysUtils" all you can is to click minus one.. :-(

Comment: "I don't understand this code" is not a good description either. I can understand your frustration trying to understand "foreign" code, but you should at least try and extract a *concise question* instead of "I don't understand". Likewise, don't mention PHP if that's nothing to do with the question. I just see a question with no specific question and PHP mentioned, so I'll just assume at this point. Now - *what do you not understand about the `ByteArraysUtils` class*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now if `paramByteOrder` is `LITTLE_ENDIAN` then the next function performs as follows:

```
public static final byte[] Long2ByteArray(long paramLong, ByteOrder paramByteOrder) {
    // create new byte array of the same size as a Java long (64 bit signed integer)
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[8];
    // wrap it using a wrapper class
    ByteBuffer localByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arrayOfByte);
    // put it in LITTLE_ENDIAN order, (only effects the next put and get methods)
    localByteBuffer.order(paramByteOrder);
    // put in the long, where the least significant bits are in arrayOfByte[0]
    // and the most significant (as well as the sign bit) in arrayOfByte[7]
    // this is different from the default BIG_ENDIAN encoding used by Java
    localByteBuffer.putLong(paramLong);
    // return it
    return arrayOfByte;
}
```

Note that the bits *inside* the bytes are not reversed.

---

If the method with the `BigInteger` parameter is called, only the least significant bits of the `BigInteger` are used, so anything above bit 64 is stripped off (without any explict check, no less, meaning that if there is data in the most significant bits, it's lost).